# SQL Server 2014, Proxy and Excel 2013

Tags: excel, ssis

Afternoon, I'm stumped and have tried suggestions posted here. I have an SSIS package executing on a 2012 Server, SQL 2014, Excel 2013. It deletes and creates an empty Excel file, were still testing. I am getting a generic error on my script task when executing through the Job Agent. I can execute the package successfully in the Catalog as well as Visual Studio.

I have checked the proxies rights in the following:

1: The launch permissions of the proxy user.
2: The folder ...windows\syswow64\config\systemprofile\
3: The destination folder.
4: Run 32 bits as well as 64.
5: The Excel Interop folder

It's a kerfuffle. Any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a relevant link, but I think the solution to your problem is to create these 2 folders:

- C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop
- C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop

When you use a proxy that needs to open excel files based on the type of OS and Excel version you have (32/64) you need one of those folders. For me it was easier to create both.

Semi-relevant link: 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b81a3c4e-62db-488b-af06-44421818ef91/excel-2007-automation-on-top-of-a-windows-server-2008-x64?forum=innovateonoffice